# How to create miniplayer like youtube with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to implement YouTube like mini player in my flutter application and have stuck. Apparently previous Stack Overflow solutions of using `mini player` package have not worked out for be as the video disposes once I open video in full screen mode.

I have been following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umhl2hakkcY tutorial for achieving so but with the actual videos. I am using `better_player` for video playback.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing the `mini_player` with `better_player` could become very hard because it would want individual controllers, what I found effective is to use https://pub.dev/packages/pip_view package and implement it from the page level.
This will give a much easier solution and a better pip.

Comment: This worked for me